# Read access violation при использовании умных указателей

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть такой код:

```
int main()
{
  unique_ptr<ProjectModel> model = unique_ptr<ProjectModel>(new ProjectModel(2));
  unique_ptr<ProjectControl> control = unique_ptr<ProjectControl>(new ProjectControl(*model));
  unique_ptr<ProjectView> view = unique_ptr<ProjectView>(new ProjectView(*control));

return 0;
}
```

При закрытии программы вылетает исключение: read access violation
В чём может быть проблема? Читал, что в main всегда нужно ловить исключения, правда ли это и на сколько корректно?

Я исправил исключение, указывающие на деструктор модели, но теперь выдаёт общее исключение read access violation. У меня следующий код:

```
class ProjectView
{
public:
    ProjectView::ProjectView(ProjectControl& control) 
         : m_control(&control) {}

private:
    const std::shared_ptr<ProjectControl>   m_control;
}

class ProjectControl 
{
public:
    ProjectControl::ProjectControl(ProjectModel& model) 
        : m_model(&model) {}
private:
    const std::shared_ptr<ProjectModel> m_model;
}
```

Comment: В целом - ваш код выглядит как неправильное использование unique_ptr. У unique_ptr может быть лишь 1 владелец, вам стоило бы использовать shared_ptr.

Comment: Проверьте деструкторы Ваших классов, скорее всего объекты уничтожаются не в том порядке, как Вам хотелось бы. В итоге, при удалении одного объекта он пытается использовать данные уже удаленного другого. Чтобы советовать что-то более конкретное, приведите [mcve].

Comment: @PavelMayorov затыкание дыр через `shared_ptr` не лучший способ, хотя наверное самый простой.

Comment: @alexolut так ведь вариантов, на самом деле, немного - или отказываться от умных указателей, или использовать `shared_ptr`. Потому что `unique_ptr` тут ну никак не подходит, хранение ссылки на объект, которым владеет `unique_ptr` где-либо еще - грубая ошибка.

Comment: Ошибка кидает в деструктор ProjectModel, но там ничего нет, вся работа у меня происходит с умными указателями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть один объект типа `ProjectModel`, управление памятью которого занимается `unique_ptr`. Далее вы передаете по ссылке этот объект в конструктор класса `ProjectControl`, который создает другой умный указатель теперь типа `shared_ptr`, но указывает на всё тот же объект. То есть жизненным циклом одного объекта управляют два умных указателя. Соответственно дважды происходит удаление. Аналогично и с классом `ProjectView`.

Вам необходимо определиться, кто должен управлять памятью объекта и в каком виде - используя исключительное (`unique_ptr`) или совместное (`shared_ptr`) владение.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Исправлю.